# From Paperscript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, libraries

I'm trying to convert one of the Paper.js library examples (http://paperjs.org/examples/smoothing/) from PaperScript to Javascript. Following the documentation, I have

- Made the scope global
- Installed the event handlers onFrame and onResize
- Created a tool and installed the event handlers onMouseMove and onMouseDown

But the canvas is not shown. I only see a couple of small blue lines: AFAIK the problem lies in the view.onFrame() function, since commenting that out at least I can see the shape, but not interact with it. The JS console dosen't show any error. What is missing?

```
    // Make the paper scope global, by injecting it into window
    paper.install(window);
    window.onload = function () {

        // Setup directly from canvas id:
        paper.setup('myCanvas');

        // Create tool
        tool = new Tool();

        var width, height, center;
        var points = 10;
        var smooth = true;
        var path = new Path();
        var mousePos = view.center / 2;
        var pathHeight = mousePos.y;
        path.fillColor = 'black';
        initializePath();

        function initializePath() {
            center = view.center;
            width = view.size.width;
            height = view.size.height / 2;
            path.segments = [];
            path.add(view.bounds.bottomLeft);
            for (var i = 1; i < points; i++) {
                var point = new Point(width / points * i, center.y);
                path.add(point);
            }
            path.add(view.bounds.bottomRight);
            path.fullySelected = true;
        }

        view.onFrame = function (event) {
            pathHeight += (center.y - mousePos.y - pathHeight) / 10;
            for (var i = 1; i < points; i++) {
                var sinSeed = event.count + (i + i % 10) * 100;
                var sinHeight = Math.sin(sinSeed / 200) * pathHeight;
                var yPos = Math.sin(sinSeed / 100) * sinHeight + height;
                path.segments[i].point.y = yPos;
            }
            if (smooth)
                path.smooth({ type: 'continuous' });
        }

        tool.onMouseMove = function (event) {
            mousePos = event.point;
        }

        tool.onMouseDown = function (event) {
            smooth = !smooth;
            if (!smooth) {
                // If smooth has been turned off, we need to reset
                // the handles of the path:
                for (var i = 0, l = path.segments.length; i < l; i++) {
                    var segment = path.segments[i];
                    segment.handleIn = segment.handleOut = null;
                }
            }
        }

        // Reposition the path whenever the window is resized:
        view.onResize = function (event) {
            initializePath();
        }


    }
```

To try it: https://jsfiddle.net/1rtkbp9s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution (credits to Stefan Krüger of the Paper.js Google Group):

```
var mousePos = view.center / 2;
```

Should have been:

```
var mousePos = view.center.divide(2);
```

The fact is that Math functions should be used instead of operators for Point and Size object... and I didn't realize that view.center IS a Point object: http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#center

Comment: awesome. It was really helpful.